# probability of having a non-zero determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, determinant

$K=\mathbb{Z}_p$ for some prime p, and $dim V = n$.

It has been shown that the number of different bases in $V$ is:

$\frac{1}{n!} \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(p^n - p^i)$  (bases which are permutations of one another are regarded as equivalent)

Derive from this that an $n x n$ matrix with elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ chosen independently at random has nonzero determinant with probability equal to $\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-p^{-i})$

Not quite sure where to start.

Comment: An $n\times n$-matrix over $K$ has nonzero determinant if and only if its columns (or equivalently its rows) form a basis of $K^n\cong V$.

Comment: so you would do $\frac{n! \frac{1}{n!} \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(p^n-p^i)}{p^n}$

Comment: There are $p^{n^2}$ matrices, since at every position we have $p$ choices.  And hint: $\prod_0^{n-1}(p^n-p^i)=\prod_1^n (p^n-p^{n-1})$.

Comment: surely $V$ has $p^n$ elements. how do you get $p^{n^2}$ matrices?

Comment: @1234 well every $n\times n$ matrix has $n^2$ entries, each of them coming from the $p$-element set $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$...............

Also what the hell is $V$?

Comment: $V$ is a vector space.

Comment: I am almost sure that this question has been asked (and answered) before, but I am not able to locate its first appearence.

Comment: Just solved it.

Comment: what I was looking for was $\frac{n! \frac{1}{n!} \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(p^n-p^i)}{(p^n)^n}$.